# Which LaTeX to install on Linux?

Tags: installing, distributions, linux

Which LaTeX distribution would you recommend for using on Linux from command line? I am looking for one with most complete coverage of packages.

Answer (score 25):

You should install [TeXlive](http://www.tug.org/texlive/).

Note some distributions like Debian derived ones (e.g. ubuntu) have a version of TeXlive in the package manager. This isn't a great option: it is old and it doesn't have all the packages you might need. Installing the one via the TUG website is much better. [See this blog discussion for arguments.](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=109427)

TeXlive comes with a variety of useful things like [`tlmgr`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html) for updating packages from CTAN and so on. This way you always have the most up to date packages.

Comment: @Seamus, LOL answers with the same content at the same time, and edits with the same content at the same time.

Comment: @Peteris yes the commands (programs actually) have the same names as in windows

Comment: @Seamus, since your answer is more verbose and descriptive, perhaps you should add the links from mine so that I may delete my answer.

Comment: @Seamus Perhaps a mention to tlcontrib is suitable too http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/

Comment: Often the TeX Live that comes with the distro is good enough unless you really need to live on the cutting edge.

Answer (score 0):

Install texlive2010, but consider installing it on its own partition. You may wish to update your Linux distri without re-installing texlive afterwards!

On the other hand I do not think it would be usefull to install texlive into your home directory.

Regards,
Alexander

Comment: The update of Unix doesn't influence the installation of TL.

Comment: @Marco You are right, but in many cases it is safer and recommended by the Distro to make a new and clean install of Linux. So I should have been writing »You may wish to install a new version of your Linux distri . . . «. And a new install might simply erease a installation under /usr/share.

Comment: The default location for TeXLive 2010 is in /usr/local/texlive/2010.  If you later want to install, e.g., TeXLive 2011, it will go into /usr/local/texlive/2011, living happily alongside TeXLive 2010.  (Of course, you'd either adjust your path or create symlinks to /usr/local/bin (etc.) to choose which one you're currently running.)