# How to install LaTeX on Fedora 15 ?

Tags: installing, linux

In order to install a framework I need to install first LaTeX on a fedora 15 machine

> - *LaTeX* (optional) This is used for typesetting K definitions. Besides basic
>     packages, the following (texlive) packages are needed: bera, datetime, ec,
>     fancybox, fancyvrb, import, marginnote, microtype, ms, pdfcomment, pgf,
>     preview, stmaryrd, times, titlesec, ucs, url, xcolor, and xkeyval.

I tried searching with yum. But I wasn't able to locate the packages. Google didn't return much either.

Any ideas ?

Comment: related : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18939/which-latex-to-install-on-linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Look here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/TeXLive) for an RPM packaged version of TeX Live 2010. There's also the 2011 pretest version, but it's safer to stick with the stable one.

As Alex points out the maintenance of these packages may not be always trustworthy, so it can be better to manually install TeX Live.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Going to try right now.. hope it countains everything I need.

Comment: It seems using this repository is not recommended: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=262135&mode=linear So better install TL2010 for yourself (See answer from BlueHatter)

Answer (score 5):

Just install TeX Live ( http://www.tug.org/texlive/ ); I did that 2 days ago and it was a much better experience than the outdated TeX Live 2007 packages provided by Fedora.

Comment: I had the same problem with Ubuntu packages --- namely, that they didn't get updated very often (there was no `tlmgr`, the texlive update manager)... So I installed TexLive. I still needed to create a dummy package to tell the system that texlive was installed.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an update:

```
yum install texlive
```

gave me a fairly up-to-date LaTeX installation for my Fedora 20 (alpha) system.  True, it installs 217 packages, but they do seem to be from a fairly current TeXLive 2013 version:

```
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
```

So maybe now that the packages seem a bit more maintained, the simplest method may be the best. And as a bonus, you don't have to deal with dependency issues that may result from not using the Fedora package repositories.